# Change Git Root Folder contents to a Subfolder

Tags: git

i have a git repository that i created some time ago, and i made the mistake of putting all the files of my project in the root git repository path. However, i discovered that i want to version control some more elements that do not really belong to the root folder.

My current git is like :

```
git_repos/file1
git_repos/file2
...
```

I would like to convert that to :

```
git_repos/demo/file1
git_repos/demo/file2
git_repos/other_folder
git_repos/other_folder/file
```

You get the idea. I know i may be able to do it by moving files, but something tells me that there is probably a better way. Is there ? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`git mv`](http://schacon.github.com/git/git-mv.html) command is what you want to use. You can move more than one file at once by ensuring that the final destination name is a directory. For example:

```
git mv file* demo/
```

Don't forget to commit the result when you're done, of course.